# how to load parts of a slow page with ajax to speed up loading in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using rails 2.3. I want to load parts of a page with some slow queries through ajax to speed up page loading. Example

```
<div id="count-projects"><%= Project.count%></div>
...
<div id="some-stuff"><%= User.count %> users and <%= Book.count%> books</div>
```

I want to rewrite the above code so that there are two ajax requests, whose responses are put into the divs withs ids 'count-projects' and  'some-stuff'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it using jquery's ajax and load functions like so:

```
jQuery.ajax({url: "/controller/action_1", 
            success: function(data){
            jQuery("#some_id").html(data);
            }});
jQuery("#some-other-id").load("/controller/action_2");
```

also, the partials views/controller/action_1.html.haml and views/controller/action_2.html.haml were used to generate the inner html for the elements #some_id and #some-other-id.

Answer (score 1):

First you'd have to create a serverside script that for example returns a JSON array

```
[
    {"name":"first project", "href":"abc.php"},
    {"name": "second project", "href":"def.php"}
]
```

When you request it via a URL (?action=getProjects would be a good name). Then I'd suggest using jQuery for request. It would enable you to use the following code

```
$.getJSON(url, {action:'getProject'}, function(json){
    $.each(json, function(i, project) {
        $('div#count-projects').append('<a href="' + project.href + '">' + project.name + '</a>');
    });
});
```

This would then get the JSON data from the server (created from database by Ruby), and create a list of links to each project etc you need for your specific solution.